# Cloud Functions deploy error during lint on Windows: "enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: windows, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Following the [firebase function getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and getting a seemingly simple error once trying to deploy with:

```
firebase deploy --only functions

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Beat\leginformant\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Beat\leginformant\$RESOURCE_DIR\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The package.json file does exist just as the tutorial shows in my project/functions/package.json.
Have tried changing or printing out the RESOURCE_DIR env with no success. Assuming it would be scoped inside of the NPM shell environment.

npm version: 5.6.0

node version: 8.9.0

Comment: Also, after running the deploy command I notice a literal $RESOURCE_DIR folder is created in my project. Putting my package.json file in this folder eliminates this error but seems wrong and just seems to "kick the can" as more errors appear after that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is a known problem with the Firebase CLI 3.17.0 through at least 3.17.3, but only on Windows.  You can fix this on your machine by editing `firebase.json` at the root of your project and replacing `$RESOURCE_DIR` with `%RESOURCE_DIR%` in the npm commands you see there.  The former is the unix syntax way to use an environment variable, whereas the latter is the Windows command shell syntax.  Since you're using Windows, you need to use the Windows syntax.

The team is looking into ways to prevent having to make changes to the config files you use, as it's not really convenient for teams that works across platform to keep changing the same file back and forth.

**EDIT: This issue should be fixed with projects created with CLI version 3.17.5.**

Comment: This totally makes sense and worked, thanks for your very quick response!

Comment: hey @DougStevenson I tried replacing  `$RESOURCE_DIR` with `%RESOURCE_DIR%` in the npm commands so that it reads : `npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint` and it still didnt work. Is there another way around this? Thanks

Comment: @DejiJames Please ask a new question the describes exactly what does not work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I asked the question here and have edited my question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48732513/7721666

Answer (score 2):

When running

```
firebase init functions
```

I use this configuration

```
? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? JavaScript
//TypeScript doesn't work
? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes
//If you don't you will get a missing file lint
? File functions/package.json already exists. Overwrite? Yes
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
//Why not
```

Then if use windows

Replace $RESOURCE_DIR by %RESOURCE_DIR% in firebase.json

Answer (score 2):

Change the following:

`npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint`

to

`npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint`

in firebase.json file in main structure

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows, while Initializing the firebase Project in CLI using `firebase init`,In `firebase.json` file,Change the code to as per below`{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}`
 
After this change, try `firebase deploy --only functions` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by accessing your `firebase.json` file and delete this line containing `RESOURCE_DIR`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other suggestions, if you change the preflight/predeploy command from:

```
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint", OR
"npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
```

to

```
"npm --prefix ./functions run lint"
```

the issue seems to get fixed. This also resolves it for both Windows and Linux.

To see more details, please see this answer (and further thread): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610#issuecomment-360147507

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `firebase.json` file as shown in here

```
"npm --prefix functions run lint"
"npm --prefix functions run build"
```

Comment: Couldn't get `RESOURCE_DIR` to work, this works consistently

Answer (score 0):

As an extra doing npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint like @Deji James said, made me some progress but still didn't work.

As a suggestion I found this
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610

and @merlinnot says here 
Hey guys, you all probably have sth in your predeploy in firebase.json, don't you? Just **delete** what you have there for now if it's not that important.

worked for me.
PS. before deciding to delete, I have done all reinstall things, uninstall things. Only this is worked.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu you need to change `firebase.json` to following, notice `$` before `RESOURCE_DIR`

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

for Windows 10 you need to change `firebase.json`n to following, notice `%` after and before `RESOURCE_DIR`

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(for Windows no idea if it work in ios or not)Just delete everything under "Predeploy":
it should look like

> "predeploy": [ ],

and this work for me hope it will solve your problem also
i find this solution [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/610#issuecomment-361081700)