# Error: functions predoploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to deploy my firebase angular js web app functions using cmd prompt :

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

however I keep getting the error code :

```
C:\Users\deji\Desktop\TNF>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'fantasyapp-a5717'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\deji\Desktop\TNF\functions
> eslint .


C:\Users\deji\Desktop\TNF\functions\index.js
  17:5   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  17:54  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  17:54  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback
  19:9   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  19:9   warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  21:9   warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback
  21:9   error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
  25:54  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback
  29:25  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback
  37:8   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
  37:8   warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  37:52  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback
  37:52  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 13 problems (6 errors, 7 warnings)
  0 errors, 5 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\deji\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-16T08_19_43_651Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is that the only thing you see?  What if you run with --debug on the command line?

Comment: @DougStevenson i have editted the question to reflect thi. Thanks. I am using a windows computer

Comment: You have a lot of ESLint errors that you need to resolve.  Please follow the advice of the lint errors to correct your code, or disable ESLint if you accept the possible errors.

Answer (score 9):

You can remove everything under "predeploy" in firebase.json, and it'll stop running the script which is causing issues.